# my jquery code doesnt have any effect after i run a javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have some **jQuery** code which works perfectly but today I've added some extra **javascript** in my page. Now **jquery** won't work anymore.

Page code is the following.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=wrapperLink;    
</script>
```

wrapperLink function is:

```js
function wrapperLink()
{
    document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.split('UDF').join('<a href=../VBAMakro/Fonksiyonlar_UDFKullaniciTanimliFonksiyonlar.aspx>UDF</a>');
}
```

With this function, I'm trying to change all `UDF` text to a link, and they really changes to links, but **jquery** gets function-less.

Comment: Where is the JQuery? Both of the functions you show appear to be the same.

Comment: By recreating the document body's entire HTML, I'd bet you're losing every single event bound to the elements you just blew away and recreated.

Comment: ceejayoz, so what should i do?

Comment: i've solved the problem with using the "p" element instead of "body" since my jquery codes don't work on p elements